# equalsIgnoreCase not working (Java)

Tags: java, string, netbeans, equals, readfile

Here is one of my methods which scans the TXT file and counts the occurrence of the word "Jan" which should be 1, since the Date in the txt file is 09-Jan-2018

```
static int getFirstMonth() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file_to_scan = new File("happyFile.txt");
    Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(file_to_scan);
    int count = 0;
    while (scannerInput.hasNext()) { 
        String nextWord = scannerInput.next(); 
        if (nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Jan")) {
            count++;      
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

[Here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1515473857515.txt) is the txt file incase anyone wants to have a look.

If I am using `nextWord.equals("Jan")` I would understand why it's not picking up because it's not the full word, but shouldn't `ignoreCase` ignore that and pick up the 3 consecutive letters? Could anyone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc on `Scanner#next()`? Do you understand how it decided what to read each time you call it?  Please start there.

Comment: It read `09-Jan-2018` and save it to `nextWord`, then  `nextWord.equalsIgnoreCase("Jan")` is `false`.

Comment: I set it so it reads every word then scans for "Jan" this is why I don't understand how it's not working.

Comment: @KylePolansky Do you feel that your comment could be a full answer? It seems very helpful to me. :)

Comment: @Keara Thanks for the suggestion. I have changed my comment to a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.equals()` will compare the entire words. In this case, `Scanner.next()` is separating words by white space, so it's reading "09-Jan-2018" into `nextWord`.

If you want to see if `nextWord` contains "Jan", consider using something like `String.contains()` and for case-insensitivity, you can convert each string to to lowercase before comparing.

For example: `if (nextWord.toLowerCase().contains("jan"))`

Comment: I just get a redline Kyle when I changed the if statement to contains instead of equals to. Something about non static method containing char sequence or something like that, also my method is an int

Comment: Wait no I've figured it out now, I was confused on the nextWord, thank you very much Kyle I'll give you best answer appreciate this.